# salesforce-marketingcloud android push no

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, cordova

I'm trying to integrate salesforce-marketingcloud Cordova plugin with an existing hybrid mobile application.

I've created firebase account and all required details for android and ios and did all the required setup for Android platform.

Next, I've installed salesforce-marketingcloud Cordova plugin into my application and started application on both ios and android phones.

I was able to see contact created for ios phone but not android, also if I add any api calls to the code eg. MCCordovaPlugin.isPushEnabled(successCallback, errorCallback);

I never get any response from the Android application but ios works.

So more info

Cordova version  7.0.0
Android version  6.3.0

When I look at the Android studio logs I don't see any errors... I can see API been called just nothing ever returns.

Any idea what could be the issue or how I could troubleshoot this?

Regards.

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?  Also, please enable logging and provide the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I've encountered is post_prepare hook not firing which means com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordovaplugin.MCCordovaPluginApplication never inserted into AndroidManifest.  The workaround is to insert it manually into your AndroidManifest until the plugin is fixed.

!!!Note this plugin assumes that there is no other plugin overwrites android:name property inside AndroidManifest . the following link describes how to get around the issue [multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

1. Have you verified the correct values present in your MCCordovaPluginApplication.java file and are set in method

MarketingCloudSdk.init(this, MarketingCloudConfig.builder()

2. Are you using Cordova platform development using Android Studio? If so have you tracked if your getting all of your correct init values logged in Logcat? You can try to set your logging and make sure you are getting "MarketingCloudSdk init finished with status:" along with other info.

MarketingCloudSdk.setLogLevel(MCLogListener.VERBOSE);

MarketingCloudSdk.setLogListener(new AndroidLogListener());

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion I will try increasing logging level...

Comment: Also yes I'm using Android Studio and I do have errors with missing R.class  but I can get around it by adding  import  package.name.R; and it fixes that issue and I'm able to build and run the application.

Comment: I've put breakpoints into MCCordovaPlugingApplication.java  and none of them got hit.  I've also put breakpoints into MCCordovaPlugin.java and I hit my breakpoint..... It looks like onCreate() inside MCCordovaPluginApplication.java never called.

Comment: ok... yes that error with "missing R.class" is often because there are no inserted values which makes sense if you're not even executing code MCCordovaPluginApplication.java file.

So a couple things. 
1. I'm going to assume your add plugin command is running successfully, or there would be issues with the iOS platform as well. So when you run the gradle sync in Android Studio what happens?

2. If you get no errors can you verify the package path looks good and agrees with dir structure? package com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordovaplugin;

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator and if so which device type and API?

Comment: Hello. I'm running on both emulator (Nexus 5x API24) and device (Samsung SM-G900I(Android 6.0.1, API 23 ).

Comment: Does anyone know if this plugin actually works with java 1.8?

Comment: Turns out 1.8 is a requirement to install a plugin so my theory it could've been java version goes out of the window.

Comment: Looks like I figured out the issue, the android post_prepare hook doesn't fire....... which means MCCordovaPlugingApplication.java never added to Android manifest file and never called... I've created hello world app in Cordova and if I manually add android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cordovaplugin.MCCordovaPlugingApplication.java"  my debug point will get hit.

Comment: another interesting observation..... so the issue is hooking not firing ......

Comment: Serge Tk... Have you seen issues before with the hooks not firing? I saw this a couple months ago and we do have a workaround, however after trying to reproduce the hooks not functioning bug, I now cannot reproduce it and in fact the hooks are working on our Marketing Cloud Cordova Plugin 1.0.2 latest and even our develop branches.

Comment: I haven't used this plugin before .... I tried it on 3 different machines 2macs and 1 windows.... only older mac successfully tried to execute hook script (but failed due to another plugin overwriting the same tag).